# Direct to URL Page on open VBScript

Tags: javascript, vbscript, asp-classic

This should be simple, I want to know how to open a new page in the same window using VBScript?

Comment: I have no clue what you're asking really.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I want to direct my user striaght to another URL on opening my VBScript.

Comment: Do you mean if they request a specific url, redirect them?

Comment: No basically, I am working with a system that only allows you to write VBScript on its own page (HTML/CSS/Javascript are fine together).  I am trying to pull data from my database using sql in vbscript then post this data to my HTML/Javascript page.  I then want to use the data in my javascript code?

Comment: You can't display your data using purely client side code.  You would need to use either the Request object to retrieve the information from the sending page or ADODB to pull data directly from the database, both of which would require server side VBS.  It might help if you post some code

Comment: You keep saying VBScript but I think you mean ASP. You have an *ASP* page that reads database information using VBScript and once you retrieve that info you need to post it immediately to another page? If that's your intention, it's doable. Conversely, you can use AJAX from your JavaScript page to call your ASP page to get the info, too. So you can work from either direction.

Answer (score 0):

steps:

1. when open page go to database
2. retrieve the records you need
3. Build URL where you want user to be redirected
4. Using response.redirect send user to desired page. It will open page in the same window.

You also can use JavaScript set.location to same url with basically same effect.
Depends on how heavy data is and how well your data retrieval methods are it could be so fast that user nor even realizes that he was not on the same page, however if browser set to alert user on redirect that would be a different story.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to redirect your page to a new page you should be able to use a redirect

really simple example vbscript:

```
Dim URL
URL = "mywebpage.com/newpage.asp"
Response.Redirect (URL)
```

this page has a few other examples:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524309%28v=vs.90%29.aspx